# Algorithm for Math.Random

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, algorithm

This was the question asked by one Interviewer. I was unable to answer.

Question was, assume you want to pick a random number from the given array.

> Condition is you are not supposed to pick anything in sequential and
>   not to use built in Random function.

I have no idea. Like to know how is this Math.Random does for us?

I googled and didn't find the implementation/logic behind that.

Any one know?

Comment: problem description is very vague.

Comment: i dont know the exact algorithm, but it has something to do with the local time ( nano seconds etc.)

Comment: @David, I guess this problem might be implemented by some 1 or an Author of C#, Java, etc. What is the logic behind it. I like to know

Comment: You want to know how Math.Random is implemened?

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator . Also, use current time as the seed.

Comment: Depending on the interview and the complexity they want, just use the last digit of the current time in milliseconds, or whatever.  Tons of solutions for this.

Comment: First you need to understand WHY a random pick is needed. Unless the purpose of the random number generation is understood it is impossible to suggest a suitable algorithm. Once it is understood you can chose the desired algorithm AND a suitable source of entropy.

Comment: That's a silly question for an interview. if I were to ask a technical question in an interview, I would ask about architectural patterns such as MVC or MVVM, techniques such as IOC, and also about cutting edge technologies such as Entity Framework or WinRT. No one cares about low-level implementation details that are already provided by most frameworks out there.

Comment: @HighCore, I could have answer to your question. But i was unable to answer when they ask question like this and another question was `Give a design for online chess program in 10 mins` .

Comment: @HighCore, I disagree with you!

Comment: @Ajay That's ok. Since you're not giving any arguments on `why` you disagree I can't say anything but "Ok".

Comment: Alright. High level talk, design pattern, software-architecting... all are good in meetings or presentations. But they don't go in day-to-day activities, when hard-core level efficient code is required. Random number generation has it importance in computer science, much-much more than MVVM/WinRT and things like that. You cannot, and being a software-guy must not ignore the algorithms, runtime complexity, performance and similar things.

Comment: @Ajay That depends on the technology stack. I work with .Net, and it works. Period. `hard-core level efficient code` is self-evident and self-produced when you apply the correct software patterns, and have deep knowledge of the phylosophy on which the framework you're using is built.

Comment: @Ajay in my day-to-day activities I don't spend my time moving bytes in memory from here to there, but instead I dedicate myself to improving the overall architecture by applying the relevant patterns, and yes, I completely ignore the low-level implementation details NO ONE cares about, at least in the area of Enterprise Business Applications.

Comment: @HighCore, You are wrong buddy. "NO ONE cares" statement says it all about your expertise. You cannot implement a pattern, or a highly scalable system without considering low-level details. It is very much important even when managed languages are playing important roles in most business applications. A well connected enterprise system must perform some action/transaction within fraction of seconds, and each and every thing gets counted. And performance is very much critical to Enterprise Systems!

Comment: Hello Highscore and Ajay why violence? :)

Comment: @Ajay that's not what Im talking about. I pretty much know what OUR code does, but I don't really care what `system.dll` does. You know what I mean? .Net already does random numbers, I don't care how. If I were to hire someone, I'd rather make sure they know how to use .Net, not some silly algorithm that is never really going to be used anywhere.

Comment: @Billa - No violence! @HighCore: As far as any interview is concerned, it is all about candidate's knowledge, his analytical abilities, his deep understanding. Interviewers ask any set of absurd questions - like to reverse a singly-linked list, print 100 numbers without using loops etc. In daily acts, you may needn't to encounter the lower-level details, but it is very much needed to know what that does. You must be confident to know what some statement (like BlockCopy) does. You cannot ignore difference between `ref` and `out` keywords. Know what I'm saying?

Comment: @Ajay in that we agree. Not knowing the difference between `ref` and `out` is not acceptable.

Comment: Eagerly waiting for c# Piano Player. JON SKEET in ACTION

Comment: And to add on that: I have interviewed many candidates having 6+ years of experience, and they aren't confident about memory allocation (forget pointers!), mutexes, overloading etc. Would you take such candidate if he/she is having 7 years of exp, has handled team of 10+, has been working in big enterprise system. How would you evaluate them?

Comment: @Ajay and @Highscore, SOF has already introduced a good platform called `Chat`. Please make use of that too :)

Answer (score 22):

So far three people have told you to use the last digit of Ticks. **This doesn't work.** Try doing so in a tight loop and you will quickly see why it is a bad idea.

The question is not very well posed. I like giving ambiguously posed questions in interviews because you get to find out how the candidate deals with an ambiguous situation. In this case I would immediately push back and find out what the interviewer means by "random". Is pseudo-randomness good enough?  Is there a source of high-quality entropy available?

Once you have a clarified question it should be easier to answer.

The problem comes down to managing entropy. If you have a very weak source of entropy -- like the value of Ticks (not the last digit, which is worthless, but the entire value) then you can use that to seed a pseudo-random-number generator. If you have a high quality source of entropy then you can just use that to generate random bits directly.

Comment: Hi @Eric, you can run my test, it works no?

Comment: What **doesn't work**? A pseudo generator simply based on the Ticks property? Of course. But the initial question of the OP was "you want to pick a random number". There are no 10 random numbers to get, **just one**. That being said, I do agree that Ticks is not the best choice for source of entropy.

Comment: @Thomas: No, your algorithm is terrible. Try running your program ten times in a row and see what you get. I get: 6,37,95,81,68,69,50,12,58,36 - 6,4,95,81,2,55,0,68,58,99 - 6,37,95,81,68,12,50,79,58,90 ... Notice anything odd?  The first number is always six, the second is usually 37, the third is always 94, the fourth is always 81... this is *incredibly awful randomness*.

Comment: First try I have 46,31,25,80,16,28,36,9,8,99 ...
By the way, we were talking in an interview context no?

Like you say without more detail you guess you want a linear distribution and nothing more.

If you start to talk about entropy I guess it is the end of the interview...

Comment: @ken2k: OK, suppose you just want *one* random number. Where in the documentation of Ticks does it say that the last digit is chosen randomly on all hardware?  Is there anything whatsoever that prevents the BCL implementers from choosing to always fill in zero as the last digit?

Comment: @Thomas: Do ten tries in a row.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, we just don't know what the last digit will return. Actually, that was the whole point of my answer and the *very source* of the randomness effect: **we just don't know** what it returns. I could also have chosen the current process ID (divided by 4) as an unknown value for example. There is no expected random-friendly distribution of this unknown value because I understood the question as "I want just one random item from this array". But again, I agree that the last digits of the current ticks count is not a good value, mainly because of the internal CPU clock resolution

Comment: @ken2k: You have put your finger on the fallacy in your reasoning.  "We don't have any knowledge of what this will return" and "we know that the returned value is reliably randomly distributed" are **opposites**, but you are treating them as **synonyms**. We cannot blithely assume that any unknown quantity is randomly distributed! It might be highly non-random. **We don't know** and therefore we shouldn't assume that the distribution happens to be the one we want.

Comment: @EricLippert Ahaha, that's the whole point of the definition of "random" :) Isn't an unpredictable value (which a value we don't know is, per definition) a *random* value? Hum, not sure about that, and it should be clarified as you said yourself: "*find out what the interviewer means by "random"*". I upvoted your answer because of this particular sentence!

Comment: @ken2k: We have to distinguish between the layperson's definition of "random", which is basically "something I don't know", and the engineer's definition of random, which is an *inherently unpredictable* process which produces results that nevertheless *reliably conform in the aggregate* to a particular distribution. It's not enough for a value to be unpredictable once; its *distribution must conform to a certain model* in the aggregate for it to be actually random.

Comment: Some more fun with duplicate counts :) 10 runs: 0 0 2 2 0 0 1 0 2 0, 100 runs: 3 3 2 2 4 0 1 2 2 2, 1000 runs: 8 9 11 19 10 9 14 11 11 8

Comment: @EricLippert Even if the question is very vague, in the context of an interview for a engineering job, I guess you're right about the definition of the expected "random".

Comment: @ken2k More specifically, unless otherwise stated, it's generally assumed that when you ask for a random number that it be evenly distributed along the range of valid values.  Any time that's not the desired goal it tends to be very explicitly stated (i.e. I want a random number following a normal distribution).

Answer (score 7):

Guaranteed to be random. (tongue *FIRMLY* in cheek):

```
void Main()
{
    Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => ComeOnItsKindaRandom(0, 10)).Dump();
}

public int ComeOnItsKindaRandom(int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    var query = "http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min={0}&max={1}&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new";
    var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format(query, minValue, maxValue));
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var body = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        return int.Parse(body);
    }
}
```

Comment: @HighCore Now, now now...the only requirement was `Condition is you are not supposed to pick anything in sequential and not to use built in Random function.` - this passes that! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to get **one item** from an array, without using the `Random` class, you could use a `modulo` function with an unknown value, such as `DateTime.Now.Ticks`:

```
string[] items = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

// Modulo items.Lenth returns a value from 0 to Length - 1
int index = (int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks % items.Length);

Console.WriteLine(items[index]);
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Ticks`. what it will give? how it got related with Math.Random?

Comment: @Billa it's not related, wasn't that the point? It gives a large number based on the current time.

Comment: @Billa It returns the current time, as a number of Ticks. There are 10K ticks in a millisecond. Random might use the current time, but the current time itself isn't related to Random.

Comment: This doesn't work. Try it in a loop and you'll see why.

Comment: @EricLippert That's basically why I said "one item". The whole point is that you can't predict the value returned by DateTime.Now the first time you call it.

Comment: Also, DateTime.Now.Ticks tends to (always?) end with `0` so it would be frequently divisible by 2, 5, and 10. This would almost certainly favour returning the same elements depending on the array length. EDIT: In my tests, array length 5 always returns `0` for index, array length 6 picks `0` or `2` always for example.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair While it is true that the distribution of the last digits returned by DateTime.Now.Ticks isn't the best distribution you could get for a Random generator, it can end with any digit (not just 0)

Comment: @ken2k Yeah, I just realized it might depend on the platform or .NET implementation. I'm just saying you need to do a bit more tweaking to the `DateTime.Now.Ticks` value rather than just directly moduloing it as-is (see Thomas' answer for example)

Comment: It can end with any digit the first time but it will always end with the *same* digit every subsequent time, which makes it unsuitable as a source of randomness. Regardless, **ticks is not documented as being a source of entropy** so don't use it as one.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Very true, is might also depends on some external parameters (CPU clock). You could tweak it a bit more, but I didn't feel the question was how to create a random generator. The idea behind my answer was to find a way to return one pseudo-random value from an array.

Comment: @EricLippert It returns same digits for subsequent calls only if the time between calls is constant. Again, I didn't understood the question as "do write a pseudo-random generator", but "do write a way to return **one** (pseudo) random element from this array".

Answer (score 4):

I would use the

```
DateTime.Now.Tick
```

And then taking just enough numbers for example for Math.Random(10), I will only take the last two numbers.

Or you can take the modulo of this tick like followed :

```
public static class MyMath
{
    private static int counter = 1;

    public static int Random(int max)
    {
        counter++;
        long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        int result = Math.Abs((int) (ticks/counter)%max);
        return result;
    }
}
```

see the following test :

```
    [Test]
    public void test()
    {
        List<int> test = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            test.Add(MyMath.Random(100));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("result:");
        foreach (int i in test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont know how this will work when i was given with 5 elements array. What i get in tick and how i would get my number?

Comment: I think it is what your interviewer expected to heard, this is the base, after obviously it is more complex, but it is the base.

Comment: @Billa Datetime.Now.Tick just give you a timestamp, a long (a number) that represent very precisely what time it is when you get this property, so for example now it is : 634994778252950613.
It changes so often that it is perfect for generating random numbers!

Comment: This algorithm is terrible; it produces highly non-random results when run multiple times.  Ticks is **not** perfect for generating random numbers. It does *not* change often compared to the processor speed, and even if it did **there is a strong correlation between the amount of work the program does and the amount that ticks has changed**. It is not *random* at all; it is *tightly correlated to the behaviour of the program*. As you'd expect; it's *timing the program*.

Comment: If you want to use ticks as a source of entropy the last thing you should be using is the low bits, because they do not change over the lifetime of the program. **Ticks is not the processors high performance counter**. The correct way to use ticks is to use its *middle bits* as a source of entropy to seed a high quality PRNG, like Mersenne Twister. You only want to use ticks *once*, not on an ongoing basis like you're doing here.

Comment: So what would have you proposed in interview? Nothing because it is not perfect? I would never hire you, I need smart person, able to find a solution. And asking this question, I do not expect the perfect random because you are rigth, the perfect random does not exist!

Comment: I said in my answer what I would have done: I would have clarified the problem until I understood what was actually required by the customer and what tools were available, and then chosen an implementation strategy based on the requirements and the tools.

Comment: @Thomas: In quantum mechanics, some scientists have argued that the hidden variable theory is wrong.  More precisely, they have offered proofs (which admittedly, may be wrong) that under certain assumptions, the hidden variable theory is either wrong or that the hidden variables are so hidden as to be impossible to discover or otherwise predict.  Given all that, it is possible that there exists a source of true perfect randomness, assuming you define perfect randomness as being completely unpredictable (which is roughly what the cryptographic definition says).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of Random numbers in C. You could try rewriting it in C#.

**Random Numbers for C: End, at last?**
http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/marsaglia-rng.html

It seems to be of very high quality.

But writing this code  in a interview mite not be easy, but you could definitely tell him the ideas used.

Answer (score 0):

Just one idea, you could use one of the last digits in `DateTime.Now.Ticks` to get a basis to choose the index. Or maybe some hash function on the same thing. Or use a web service that can give you random numbers measured from radiation. `Math.Random` just picks from predefined tables (yes indeed, it's not truly random).

Comment: Try actually looking at the last digit of Ticks and you'll quickly see why this doesn't work.

Comment: @EricLippert I know there are many zeroes, which is why I said "one of the last".. I'm sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I think they were just seeing if you knew about [LCG (Linear Congruential Generator)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) algorithms.

The maths behind them is somewhat tricky however, so I doubt they could expect you to be able to write one off the top of your head.

But failing that, couldn't you just cheat like this to generate a random index?

`int index = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode() % array.Length;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's known as Pseudo-Random not just Random, since Random series is impossible to generate in a computational form,

Most Pseudo-Random number generators PRNG are on this form:

at Time 0: R(0) = Random(Seed)

at Time i: R(i) = Random(R(i-1));

Second, Random doesn't mean you don't know what will the ith outcome, but that the series is robust & it's very difficult to guess the formula or the seed given chain of outcomes

Hope this helps